# How to return Sqlalchemy result as JSON?

Tags: jquery, python, sqlalchemy, pylons

The Sqlalchemy result can have 0 to many records.

Result is:

```
record = meta.Session.query(model.EmpsTable).filter(model.EmpsTable
         .firstname.like(searchQuery))
```

If there was only one record to return I would do:

```
return {'file_id':record.file_id, 'filename':
         record.filename, 'links_to' :record.url}
```

I can print the records on terminal like such:

```
for r in record:
    print r.file_id
```

But in this case I need to send these multiple records as JSON reply to a JQuery ajax.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, don't call `record` an object that is a query, collection, instrumented sequence/whatever... then you can just get a list of dictionaries.

```
qry = meta.Session.query(model.EmpsTable).filter(model.EmpsTable
         .firstname.like(searchQuery))

return {'data': [
         {'file_id':record.file_id, 'filename':
            record.filename, 'links_to' :record.url}
        for record in qry
       ]}
```

To convert the returned object into JSON, you might already have decorated your method for that, or just call json.dumps() over it.

UPDATE: for security reasons, as pointed out [by @MrGhimire](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security) it's better to wrap the list in a dictionary.

Comment: Did that but I'm now getting this warning:
'WARNI [pylons.decorators] [worker 1] JSON responses with Array envelopes are susceptible to cross-site data leak attacks'

Comment: @MrGhimire: Check here for why it's a security issue: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security

Comment: @mouad Thanks, that made the issue crystal clear.

Do you know any safe alternative to it (not necessarily using JSON)?

Comment: If I understood correctly, just wrap the list in an object: { 'data': [ {...} for record in qry ] }